# Path problems when deploying servlet as a shared jar lib on Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, servlets, logback

I developed and tested an application as a War file, and very late in the game the company DevOps has dictated that the application I am working on will be deployed as a shared Jar file. The deployment environment is Tomcat6 on Windows Server 2008R2.

Multiple (~100) instances of the web application are run as separate Tomcat instances. The problem I'm trying to get around is that my logging configuration file, `logback.xml`, cannot be located by the application once the application jar is moved from the instance lib to the tomcat lib. It looks a little like this:

```
/root/tomcat6/
          bin/
          lib/
              myapp.jar
          conf/
          ...  
      myapp_inst1/
          myapp.properties  <-- yes, this is an odd place for props
          bin/
              installmyapp.bat  <-- custom scripts to install and run as win service
              startmyapp.bat        and set catalina home and work
              stopmyapp.bat
          conf/
              web.xml
              server.xml <-- port, etc., changed for instance
          webapp/
              ROOT/
                  WEB-INF/
                      lib/  <-- empty!
                      classes/
                          logback.xml
                      web.xml <-- refers to servlet class in myapp.jar                          
      myapp_inst2/
          ...
      myapp_inst3/
          ...
```

My understanding is that the logger I'm using, Logback under Slf4j, simply uses the classpath to locate the `logback.xml` configuration file (from http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html).

My understanding, too, is that Tomcat constructs its own classpaths, and that these should include the application `lib/`, application `classes/` and `tomcat/lib/` directories (http://www.mulesoft.com/tcat/tomcat-classpath). However, when I move my application jar file outside of the application `lib/` directory, the logback settings that I set in `logback.xml` no longer take effect.

Does anyone know why the application no longer finds the configuration file, and more importantly, how to fix this? The only thing I can think of is that the Tomcat application context classloaders can use the Tomcat common classloader, but not vice versa (but then how do you get around this?)

A big requirement for me is that the application log files must be separate and permit customization on a per-instance basis, so I don't think copying it into `tomcat/lib` is going to get me there. Any ideas?

- EDIT -

The root of my problem seems to be the tomcat classpath. With the web application entry point being the servlet in tomcat's common class loader, whatever it does find in the application context class loader isn't available to the app. Bummer.

I am trying to think of ways around this. What do you think?

1) Refactor the servlet instance to be something very, very generic, so that it will never need to be changed for the life of the product. I'm talking a bare shell of a servlet. This class would then be loaded by the application context loader and could "find" the rest of the application, which can be maintained, in a jar in a shared location.

2) Instead of the servlet, create an instance of a servlet lifecycle object, like a `ServletContextListener`, which would, for instance, fetch a `logger` object. Again this would be coded as a bare minimum with the intent that it never, ever changes. This might be easier with a context listener instead of the servlet itself. In principle would this force the application context into scope?

Comment: Your app jar should be under WEB-INF/lib. Not in Tomcat's classpath.

Comment: You answered the first part of your question already. Standard classloader hierarchies delegate work in the parent-direction, never the other way. If you wanted to do that you'd have to use your own, custom classloader. Have look at [this article](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/classloading-in-dse-analytics) for a similar scenario.

Comment: @Ralf what I meant to ask was whether or not it was really a hierarchy  and worked only in one direction - I think you just answered that. I wasn't sure. Now I have to figure out how to get around this.

Comment: @jb-nizet I agree in principle that the app jar should be in WEB-INF/lib, but as I said I have no choice in this. The application does function with the jar in tomcat/lib but this logging file configuration is the last thing I have to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

Deploying your webapp as a shared jar sounds like a bad idea. What's the rationale behind it?

What you could do instead is to separate it in two jars. One jar for the common library stuff that you put under `tomcat/lib`, and another jar for the application-specific stuff (like the `logback.xml` file) that you put under the webapp's `WEB-INF/lib`.

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21293344/web-app-and-dependency-jars-moved-to-tomcat-6-lib-directory-logback-cant-find) (oh, I just noticed it was also from you :).

Comment: It's maddening, but this is driven by DevOps, which seems to be the only group that is listened to at my company. We have a server which is running over a hundred instances of this app, each in it's own tomcat instance. DevOps wants to be able to swap out a single jar file on the machine to update all 100+ instances at the same time. We do want 100+ copies of logback.xml and it isn't in the jar - seem my pretty diagram :)

Comment: Lol, yeah, I had to ask once to understand what was going on, but left myself open to "move the jar" answers and similar structural changes. At this point my structure is etched in stone and I have to find out specifically how to make these properties visible. I was hoping there was some tomcat magic with the classpath (tomcat seems to have lots of corner-case config options) or (ugh) rolling my own class loader.

Comment: Ah ok I see, the `logback.xml` is not in the jar. Why is my suggestion of creating symlinks to common jars under `WEB-INF/lib` not working (my other answer)?

Comment: This is actually our "standard" deployment model for other apps as well. I'm pretty new to the company and am having a tough time with this way of thinking, but basically the main DevOp successfully argued with our CTO that symlinks into a web app container would be "bad engineering". I tried not to choke at the irony.

Comment: Maybe you could try to use Context Selectors, as described here: http://logback.qos.ch/manual/loggingSeparation.html Never tried that myself. You could also ask your DevOp to fix the problem since he's so good at "engineering" ;)